# Ruby OpenSSL hmac return unexpected result

Tags: ruby, openssl

I'm having trouble with OpenSSL using Ruby. I'm trying to do the hmac using SHA512 but the result I get from ruby it's not the same I got using openssl.

This is what I'm doing in Ruby

```
parent_chain_code  = "18ee0c9e49d8382e9f9b14633503c583145bc9499db55dcff153904f6f6c4116"
parent_private_key = "b39586851d52222a098455b1283de23b3b984da16a492d96a4f62189677b8495"
parent_public_key  = "03525cbe17e87969013e6457c765594580dc803a8497052d7c1efb0ef401f68bd5"
i = 0 # child index number

# Prepare data and key to put through HMAC function
data = [parent_public_key].pack("H*") + [i].pack("N") # public key + index
key = [parent_chain_code].pack("H*") # chain code is key for hmac

puts data.unpack("H*") # 03525cbe17e87969013e6457c765594580dc803a8497052d7c1efb0ef401f68bd500000000
puts key.unpack("H*") # 18ee0c9e49d8382e9f9b14633503c583145bc9499db55dcff153904f6f6c4116

hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA512.new, key, data) # digest, key, data

puts hmac # 185894565afcf5a77ee24882f08d0dbe835aaf4e11c436ca26717063fd1b6be715d3e0a59e133a7c8c2eb7aad7e64361cb921482a8573e82a3b49202a0420f0f
```

Then I'm using directly openssl to do the same thing:

`echo -n 03525cbe17e87969013e6457c765594580dc803a8497052d7c1efb0ef401f68bd500000000 | openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac "18ee0c9e49d8382e9f9b14633503c583145bc9499db55dcff153904f6f6c4116"`

But I got a different result -> d093b1cb4a85e042f8997bc849b1367949a2c54676c552782e81d38818263bc49b93c8a853ac5cdce573a34e74f2c4000e7ad6f0d1426b75090da1ba701050c5

Why is that?